# Add a tableView to keyWindow, how can I let it show the navigationItem

Tags: ios, window, tableview, navigationitem

I just want to add a tableview to the key window，but i can't see the navigationItem.
How can i make it appear.
I know I can push it to a navigationController, but in here I want add it to the window.
So, how can i do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A view controller's navigationItem only appears if the view controller is put into a navigation controller. It is the navigation controller that displays a view controller's navigation item. If you want the view controller's navigation item displayed (in a navigation bar), then create a UINavigationController passing in your UITableViewController as its root view controller. Then make the navigation controller the window's root view controller. You will now have a navigation bar at the top showing the table view controller's navigation item and the table view filling the rest of the screen.

Comment: I think you is right.But if it put into a navigation controller, how can i dismiss it.

Comment: Can I use "self.navigationController.view removeFromSuperview" in a button's action? I think it is a bit strange to operate it's superview, or it's just fine when is in navigationController?

Comment: My english is not good, I hope you can understand me!

Comment: Since your question was closed, you should post another question if needed.